# Ruby on Rails updating devise user attributes without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passwords, devise

I have two classes of accounts in my application. I'm trying to update the attributes of one of them (Investors). They are created using one form via devise. As a result, when an investor tries to update their account information, the form requires that they provide and confirm their password. I would like for them to be able to edit (First name, last name, etc) without having to input their password unless they want to change their password with those fields.

Here is my update method in the Investor controller

```
 def update

    session[:investor_params] ||= {}
    session[:investor_params].deep_merge!(params[:investor]) if params[:investor].present?

    @investor.attributes = session[:investor_params]

    params[:investor_params].delete(:password) if params[:investor_params][:password].blank?
    params[:investor_params].delete(:password_confirmation) if params[:investor_params][:password_confirmation].blank?
    respond_to do |format|
    if @investor.update_attributes(params[:investor_params]) 
      session[:investor_params] = nil
      sign_in(@investor.account, :bypass => true)
      format.html { redirect_to(projects_url, :notice => 'Investor was successfully updated.') }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @investor, :status => :created, :location => @investor }

    else
      format.html { render :action => "edit", :layout => "investor" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @investor.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
    end
  end
```

Here is my registrations controller

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  layout "index"

  protected

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    new_user_url(:account => resource)
  end
end
```

Here's my routes.rb

```
  devise_for :accounts, :controllers => { 
    :registrations => 'registrations',
    :passwords     => 'passwords',
    :sessions      => 'sessions' }
  devise_scope :account do
    root :to => 'registrations#new'
```

And this is a portion of my investor model that references attributes for the account model.

```
class Investor < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_one :account, :as => :profile

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :account
```

Here is the portion of the account model that is referenced

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :invited_by, :invited_by_id
```

I tried the recommendations on the devise github repo but I wasn't able to get it working for me.

If you have any suggestions or if I am missing anything, please let me know!

Answer (score 3):

Are you sending a :current_password anywhere in your params? (even if it is blank?) Normally devise wants you to use [#update_with_password](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb#L52) when requiring a password, so I'm not sure why you are getting this with :update_attributes.

Comment: I don't know where the devise file that contains the update_with_password method; devise is installed as a gem though, do you know where I can find it?

Comment: If you're using bundler/textmate you can use "mate $(bundle show devise)" from the command line to edit the gem's source. Otherwise it should be in your $GEM_HOME path. In the gem's source you can view the method in the: lib/devise/models/database_authenticatable.rb

You'll only want to use this method if you _want_ to require a password while updating. Try checking to see if you're accidentally passing in params[:current_password]

Comment: Thanks so much for you help so far, I'm a bit new at this. I actually want to update without requiring a password. My form has all the fields that can be updated, including password and password_confirmation. I want to be able update the rest of the information without having to put anything in the fields for password and password_confirmation. When I do that, I get an error message saying that they can't be blank. Also, :current_password isn't defined anywhere in our project files, but it is defined in devise gem source; is that what you were referring to?

Comment: I figured it out. It turns out that the :password param was in a hash within the :investor params. Thank you for all your help!